# Python '&' Character is missing

Tags: python, wxpython

When I use wx python to create a button with a file name as the button label, I lose the `&` character that is inside of the file names.

If a file were named: `hello&goodbye.txt`, the button would read: `hellogoodbye.txt`

I have no idea where the `&` character goes and would love a little help here.

Comment: I'm guessing it's being interpreted as the accelerator key indicator. Try escaping it to `&&` before you set the text.

Comment: Do you need an ampersand in a filename?

Comment: Yes, I am going to be using this button to open a file with that exact name when clicked. The ampersand is non-negotiable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&` character is a special symbol for those kinds of buttons. It defines what key you press to use a keyboard shortcut.

&x - [Alt]+[x] hotkey shortcut. You can escape it by using a second: `&&` -> '&' char

Comment: @Daenyth That’s a nice edit but it was fundamental enough to actually merit an own answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Better one solid answer than a solid one and a duplicate that's less clear. I'm not really in it for the rep.

Comment: The clarification did help me out. Thanks Daenyth.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand seems to be some kind of token. Have a read [here](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Ampersand-in-static-text-control-td2358418.html). It basically says this:

> Found the answer: two ampersands.